# Click events in Winform UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have a UserControl which acts like a basic button control (it is hand drawn).

I have noticed however that when I repeatedly click the control (fast) that I don't get all the click events that I would expect. If I click slowly I do get one click event per physical click.

Can anyone suggest why this is and how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**I think the clicks are converted into double clicks.**

Try adding the following line to the constructor:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, false);
```

Comment: Yup.  Or just use the MouseUp event, that's better.

Comment: Why is that better? If the control doesn't support double click, it should disable double click. Don't you think?

Answer (score -1):

If you're previous click event code isnt finished yet the next 'click' could be ignored.